# Multiple RD web access sites on same RDS web access server?

Tags: windows-server-2012, website, rds

I have a single Windows 2012 R2 server with all three required roles for RDS. This RDS deployment is strictly for remote apps. We recently acquired Symantec VIP to enable two-factor authentication for VPN and corporate site access. The RDS website was integrated with Symantec VIP and now requires a "pin" (along with AD credentials) to access.
Problem is, internal users would like to access without the "pin" requirement but still have the functionality when accessing externally. Can I just copy the RDWeb application in IIS and have regular site and other "pin" enabled? Is this even possible? Or, do I need to setup another RD web access server?

Basically have this: 
https://servername/RDweb (no pin required)
https://servername/ExternalRDWeb (pin required)

Comment: Why would you want to circumvent it for internal connections? Do you implicitly trust the internal connections simply because they're internal?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another RDS web access server to do this, but in theory, this isn't a bad thing since it allows you to treat the two zones differently.